# Why is map opening at the same locaion? Xamarin.Forms()

Tags: google-maps, listview, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm developing an app  that is supposed to open a map either on android or IOS.
The problem that i'm facing (on Android, IOS still not tested) is that it opens the map, always at the same location which seems to be my location, instead of the defined location.
Here is my code...

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        storesList.BackgroundColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        storesList.SeparatorColor=Color.White;
        storesList.ItemSelected += CellSelected;
        storesList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var storeCell = new StoreCell();
            storeCell.SetBinding(StoreCell.NameProperty, "Name");
            storeCell.SetBinding(StoreCell.LocationProperty, "Location");
            storeCell.SetBinding(StoreCell.ScheduleProperty, "Schedule");

            return storeCell;
        });

        Stores = new ObservableCollection<Store>();

        Store store1 = new Store
        {
            Name = "Pombal",
            Location = new Coordinate(39.9143958, -8.6297282).ToString()
        };
        Store store2 = new Store
        {
            Name = "Unknown",
            Location = new Coordinate(39.7301803, -8.8438668).ToString(),
            Schedule = "09:00-12:30 / 13:30-18:00"
        };

        Stores.Add(store1);
        Stores.Add(store2);
        Stores.Add(store1);
        Stores.Add(store2);
        Stores.Add(store1);
        Stores.Add(store2);
        Stores.Add(store1);
        Stores.Add(store2);
        storesList.ItemsSource = Stores;

    }

    void CellSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var address = ((Store)e.SelectedItem).Location.Replace(" ", "");
        //storesList.SelectedItem = null;

        Uri uri;
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                 uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://maps.apple.com/?q={0}", address));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(uri);
                Device.OpenUri(uri);
            break;

            case Device.Android:
                uri = new Uri("geo:" + address);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(uri);
                Device.OpenUri(uri);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Also if you could help me the item of the list is not deselecting where do i have to place this `storesList.SelectedItem = null;` so that when i return to my app i can select the same item as i did before (it is not working where i have it, i get null reference exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not constructing your map URL correctly:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393
```

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)